# Wikitude camera projection Matrix Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, wikitude

I am working on a project in `Wikitude` Unity. I had used `Vuforia` earlier.

In `Vuforia` there is a method that returns Camera projection matrix  `VuforiaUnity.GetProjectionGL()`. I need an equivalent in `Wikitude` Unity.

I guess native methods are available in Wikitude android and iOS.

Can anyone help me in getting a `Wikitude` method that returns camera projection matrix. Pardon me if there are any mistakes in my question as I am a beginner in this case.

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the projection matrix, simply call camera.projectionMatrix on the camera component attached to WikitudeCamera.